# How to generate ccFPSImage.c file in cocos2d-x

Tags: cocos2d-x, libpng

I found in cocos2d-x library, there is a file named ccFPSImage.c which is a hex format array of the FPS images. Cocos2D-x use it for displaying FPS.

I just want to know how I can generate that file.

The file content is like this:

```
unsigned char cc_fps_images_png[] = {
  0x89, 0x50, 0x4e, 0x47, 0x0d, 0x0a, 0x1a, 0x0a, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0d,
  0x49, 0x48, 0x44, 0x52, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0xe7, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x36,
  0x08, 0x06, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xa5, 0x74, 0xe8, 0xab, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0a,
  0x41, 0x69, 0x43, 0x43, 0x50, 0x49, 0x43, 0x43, 0x20, 0x50, 0x72, 0x6f,
  0x66, 0x69, 0x6c, 0x65, 0x00, 0x00, 0x48, 0x0d, 0x9d, 0x96, 0x77, 0x54,
  0x53, 0xd9, 0x16, 0x87, 0xcf, 0xbd, 0x37, 0xbd, 0xd0, 0x12, 0x22, 0x20,
.... (There are a lot of hex values here, I just omit them here)
}
```

I have use the ImageMagick tool to generate the .h file, but when it loaded, it just report:

```
cocos2d: the file is not a dds file!
cocos3d: the file is not a ktx file!
Image WARNING: unsupport true color tga data pixel format. FILE: 
Fails: init fps_images
cocos2d: the file is not a dds file!
cocos3d: the file is not a ktx file!
Image WARNING: unsupport true color tga data pixel format. FILE: 
Fails: init fps_images
cocos2d: the file is not a dds file!
cocos3d: the file is not a ktx file!
Image WARNING: unsupport true color tga data pixel format. FILE: 
Fails: init fps_images
```

I use the following command to generate the .h file:

```
convert fps.png h:->fps.h
```

Does anyone know how to generate a valid ccFPSImage.c file?

Thanks.

Comment: any "data/file to .h" converter can do the job

Comment: @LearnCocos2D Could you give me an example? I'm using MacOSX.

Comment: https://www.google.de/search?q=file+to+.h+converter&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=en&client=safari#hl=en&q=file+to+c+header+converter

Comment: @子龙山人 Can you explain how you created the array, and loaded the image ?

Answer (score 0):

Until now, ImageMagick's "convert file h:file.h" would create a header file containing either a GIF or a PPM image.

ImageMagick version 6.9.1-10 will support a new "-define h:format=PNG" option that will create the file you expected.

```
convert fps.png -define h:format=PNG -define png:exclude-chunks=all h:fps.h
```

(The "-define png:exclude-chunks=all" will cause convert to omit unwanted ancillary PNG chunks containing create/modify date, etc.)

JPEG output will also be supported, via "-define h:format=JPG".